# Changing clause of condition to absolute phrase and participle w

Tags: conditionals, clauses, subordinate-clauses, participles, absolute-constructions

1a. *When I have money I will buy a car*.

2a. *If my parents allow I'll go abroad*.

Can these sentence be changed into a absolute participle phrase? For example

1b. *Having money, I'll buy a car.*

2b. *Parents allowing, I'll go abroad.*

Comment: Not unless you lose the balls.

Answer (score 1):

(I) The problem with your first example is that

- (1b) *Having money, I'll buy a car.*

defaults to the reading/s

- (1a') *I have the money; I'll buy a car.* **or**
- (1a'') *I have the money, so I'll buy a car.*

unless there is context forcing a different timeframe, such as

- (1bb) *I'll have made tens of thousands by this time next year. Having money, I'll buy a car.*

Standalone, it is unacceptable to reduce your first sentence in this way.

..................

(II) I'd not use 'allow' without a direct object; I'd choose

- (2a') *If my parents allow me to / let me[,] I'll go abroad.*

........

- (3b) *Weather permitting, we'll get there by Thursday.*

shows a fully idiomatic use of a near-identical absolute clause to the one you suggest. I'd say, however, that

- (2b') *Parents permitting, I'll go abroad next year*

is at least partly tongue-in-cheek (so fine in a humorous or rueful conversation) whereas 'Parents allowing, ...', which doesn't mimic the archetypal example so closely, sounds a little unnatural. Not ungrammatical, and not giving an unintended meaning, but I'd find an alternative.

Comment: Summer coming, people will go to beach. When summer comes people will go to beach. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally sent the message half written. Please read again

Comment: You need 'go to **the** beach'. 'With summer coming, people will go to the beach' is far more idiomatic here. Absolute clauses  can sound unnatural, and need to be chosen with care. There's only this hit on Google for "Parents allowing, I'll" and none for "Parents allowing, we'll". You're probably best sticking closely with examples you find in reliable sources (try Nordquist at ThoughtCo; he gives a few good quotes).